# Issue with the exit code of a nohup command in unix

Tags: linux, shell-script, nohup

I have been trying to figure out on how to capture the exit status of the nohup command and then send a mail based on the status.

Below is my code:

```
if [[ "" !=  "$PID" ]]; then
    echo "killing $PID"
    kill -9 $PID
    nohup java -jar Xyz-port-0.0.1.jar &
    << Exit Code and then send mail if Exit 
      code is 0>>
    else 
    echo "Process doesn't exist"
    fi
```

Comment: Tangentially related: [When should I not kill -9 a process?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/8916)

Comment: @Kusalananda Not what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will capture the exit code of your process more reliably:

### parent.sh

```
...
java -jar Xyz-port-0.0.1.jar > /dev/null & #optionally discard stdout of java
child=$!
wait $child
exit_status=$?
if [[ "$exit_status" -ne 0 ]]; then
    # handle error
else
    #handle success
fi
```

### Wait

Note the call to `wait` will block indefinitly, so if you need to set an arbitrary limit on the amount of time you give the `java` command to complete, you might replace the call to `wait` with a loop and some manual checks to `ps` to see it the process is still running. This would allow you to set a watchdog and call everybody out of the pool if the process hangs.

### Nohup

If you need to run the java process and handle its exit code without being in an active terminal session, call your parent script (above) with `nohup` not the `java` code. The parent script could be `nohup`ed and will survive in the background with no controlling terminal and do the emailing or cleanup reliably.

Comment: Perfect ..that's what i was looking for..although i couldn't get "you might replace the call to wait with a loop and some manual checks to ps to see it the process is still running"
 Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 3):

A background job is *always* started successfully:

```
$ sntaoehu &
[1] 33566
$ bash: sntaoehu: command not found
[1]+  Exit 127                sntaoehu
$ echo $?
0
```

You can't launch your Java program in the background and detect whether that went well or not until the `nohup` command has terminated.  The `nohup` command will terminate if it can't find or start `java`, or whenever the Java program terminates.  It is not `nohup` that runs your program in the background. It just makes your program ignore any `HUP` signal and will hang around until your program terminates, and then it returns the program's exit status to the invoking shell.

To send an email if the job launched *failed*, you may do

```
(
    nohup java -jar Xyz-port-0.0.1.jar
    status=$?
    if [ "$status" -eq 126 ] || [ "$status" -eq 127 ]; then
        # something wrong in launching java
        echo 'nohup failed to run java'
        printf 'nohup exit status is %s\n' "$status"
    elif [ "$status" -ne 0 ]; then
        # the java code returned an error
        echo 'java returned an error'
        printf 'java exit status is %s\n' "$status"
    else
        # everything went well and java exited ok
        echo 'java exited safely'
    fi | mail -s 'java job status report' me@example.com
) &

echo 'started background job'
```

I.e., start a backgrounded subshell in which you run your program, then test whether `nohup` returned 126 or 127.  It will do this if the `java` command could not be found or could not be started.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to put this in my code?

Comment: @user3901666 See updated answer.

Comment: As per the below post.. wait might wait for forever..he only way the actual nohup command would return an exit code is if the java command could not be found or executed, or if the nohup command itself had an internal error

Comment: Whats your take on that?

Comment: @user3901666 `nohup` will return a specific exit code if the Java program can not be found, this is true. This will be a status of 127. If the Java program was started okay, then `nohup` would return the exit status of the Java program _when that program terminates_.

Comment: @user3901666 I think we've been misunderstanding you.  I will update the answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not necessarily the `nohup` command, but the `&` at the end of the command line.

The man page for `bash` says:

> If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell. The shell does not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0.

Technically, the shell forks a subshell to execute the `nohup ...` command, and the main shell executing the script immediately proceeds to the next command in the script. So, when the main shell executes the line after the `nohup ... &` line, the nohup command may not have exited yet: the subshell might be in the process of loading it for execution.

And the `nohup` command does not necessarily exit as such: it sets the signal handler to ignore the HUP signal, and then attempts to directly `exec()` the `java ...` command. If the `exec()` system call is successful, then the process that was `nohup` transforms into `java` *without `fork()`ing a new process and exiting*, and so there will be no exit code to return yet.

The only way the actual `nohup` command would return an exit code is if the `java` command could not be found or executed, or if the `nohup` command itself had an internal error. If the `exec()` system call is successful, the only time an exit code will be available is when the `java` command itself ends.

This is also why trying something like this does not do what you want:

```
nohup java -jar Xyz-port-0.0.1.jar &
wait $! 
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error in running Java"
fi
```

If `nohup` fails in the background, `wait` will pick up its exit code and allow it to be checked; but if `nohup` is successful in starting `java`, then the `wait` command will keep waiting until the `java` exits, since both `nohup` and `java` will be run in the same process one after another.

You might want to do something like this, as @datUser suggested:

```
STARTWAIT=20 #number of seconds to wait after starting the service

nohup java -jar Xyz-port-0.0.1.jar &
NEWPID=$!
for i in $(seq $STARTWAIT); do
    # test if the process still exists
    if ! kill -0 $NEWPID 2>/dev/null; then
        # Process has died: get its exit code, report error, stop waiting
        wait $!
        EXITCODE=$?
        echo "Process died after restart and reported result $EXITCODE" >&2
        break
    fi
    sleep 1
done
if kill -0 $NEWPID; then
    echo "The process was started and is still alive after $STARTWAIT seconds"
    echo "so I guess it's now running correctly"
fi
```

Please note that my script solution has an inherent weakness: if the `nohup`ped process dies and another process receives the same PID number within one second, this script will fail to notice that it's no longer the same process. (But if your PID numbers are getting recycled that fast, you probably have bigger problems.)

To optimally solve the problem, you would need the script to set up a time-out mechanism of some sort that would stop the `wait` command at some pre-determined time, and then run the `wait()` system call on the monitored process (which is achieved by the `wait` shell command) because that is something only the actual parent of the monitored process can do. This is quite tricky to implement in a shell script.

Comment: So what's the solution then?

Comment: Edited after a bit of testing, thinking and re-testing. :-)